# Why optimization is not applied when I do LEFT JOIN?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

[I already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67492673/4632019) why column is not pushed down and optimization is not applied.
And get detailed explanation at [mail list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAApHDvrayMkhak9eYbhHs67XvkZSOiscxJEER2yECN-k4L91oQ%40mail.gmail.com)

There were problem when I used `whole-row` vars. But here I do not use them.
Query goes work slow when I do `LEFT JOIN` or put this `LEFT JOIN` inside `CTE`.

When I run query directly (or put condition inside) it takes only [6ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/fHjJ) to run:

```sql
WITH ready AS (
SELECT
  agreement_id, sys_period, app_period,
  acc_i.ready             as acc_i_ready,
  acc_i.acc_period        as acc_i_period,
  acc_i.consumed_period   as acc_i_consumed_period,
  acc_u.ready             as acc_u_ready,
  acc_u.acc_period        as acc_u_period,
  acc_u.consumed_period   as acc_u_consumed_period
FROM "order_bt" o
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Invoice', app_period(), o ) acc_i ON acc_i.ready
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Usage',   app_period(), o ) acc_u ON acc_u.ready

WHERE o.sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  o.app_period && app_period()
 AND agreement_id = 1736
)
SELECT * 
FROM ready
```

When I just repeat condition outside it takes [45ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/hqzZ)

```sql
WITH ready AS (
SELECT
  agreement_id, sys_period, app_period,
  acc_i.ready             as acc_i_ready,
  acc_i.acc_period        as acc_i_period,
  acc_i.consumed_period   as acc_i_consumed_period,
  acc_u.ready             as acc_u_ready,
  acc_u.acc_period        as acc_u_period,
  acc_u.consumed_period   as acc_u_consumed_period
FROM "order_bt" o
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Invoice', app_period(), o ) acc_i ON acc_i.ready
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Usage',   app_period(), o ) acc_u ON acc_u.ready

WHERE o.sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  o.app_period && app_period()
 AND agreement_id = 1736
)
SELECT * 
FROM ready
-- NOTICE: I only repeat this!
WHERE sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  app_period && app_period()
 AND agreement_id = 1736
```

When I split condition it takes [671ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/VKsu):

```sql
WITH ready AS (
SELECT
  agreement_id, sys_period, app_period,
  acc_i.ready             as acc_i_ready,
  acc_i.acc_period        as acc_i_period,
  acc_i.consumed_period   as acc_i_consumed_period,
  acc_u.ready             as acc_u_ready,
  acc_u.acc_period        as acc_u_period,
  acc_u.consumed_period   as acc_u_consumed_period
FROM "order_bt" o
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Invoice', app_period(), o ) acc_i ON acc_i.ready
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Usage',   app_period(), o ) acc_u ON acc_u.ready

WHERE o.sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  o.app_period && app_period()
)
SELECT * 
FROM ready
WHERE 
 agreement_id = 1736  -- Unfortunately this is not used for index scan =( Why???
```

When I move all conditions outside it takes already [11084ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/yR1W):
(hmmm, but I do not break [inline condition](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions), does I?)

```sql
WITH ready AS (
SELECT
  agreement_id, sys_period, app_period,
  acc_i.ready             as acc_i_ready,
  acc_i.acc_period        as acc_i_period,
  acc_i.consumed_period   as acc_i_consumed_period,
  acc_u.ready             as acc_u_ready,
  acc_u.acc_period        as acc_u_period,
  acc_u.consumed_period   as acc_u_consumed_period
FROM "order_bt" o
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Invoice', app_period(), o ) acc_i ON acc_i.ready
LEFT JOIN acc_ready( 'Usage',   app_period(), o ) acc_u ON acc_u.ready
)
SELECT * 
FROM ready
WHERE sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  app_period && app_period()
 AND agreement_id = 1736
```

And when I remove `LEFT JOIN` it takes only [5ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/uLMG)!

```sql
WITH ready AS (
SELECT
  agreement_id, sys_period, app_period
FROM "order_bt" o
)
SELECT * 
FROM ready
WHERE sys_period @> sys_time()  AND  app_period && app_period()
 AND agreement_id = 1736
```

Compare: [6ms](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/hmd#plan) VS [45ms](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/VXF#plan) VS [671ms](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/rEo#plan) VS [11084ms](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/bP7#plan) VS [5ms](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/w6K#plan)
Same on depesz: [6ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/fHjJ) VS [45ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/hqzZ) VS [671ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/VKsu) VS [11084ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/yR1W) VS [5ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/uLMG)

Why second, third and forth queries are not optimized like first/last queries?
Is there some workarounds for forth case to make it work fast?
(like to select additionally fields which is described at mailing list (see links above))

PS. Second case seems to me **counter intuitive** and is not expected behavior

Server version is 13.1

---

**first - when condition is only inside CTE*
**second - when this condition copied outside CTE*

**UPD  Further investigations:**

try **I1**

Here, when function is volatile for first and second cases `BitmapHeapScan` is applied over two indexes:
`order_idx_agreement_id`, `order_id_sys_period_app_period_excl`

[9ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/fHjJ) VS [45ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/hqzZ)

---

try **I2**

After changing `acc_ready` function to `STABLE`,
for first query `BitmapHeapScan` is used.
for second query `IndexScan` is used (by mistake?).
Compare [7ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/tjrYT)  VS [11ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/dMbr)

Here we see that inlining saves for us 2ms
and 34ms (because no JIT generation).
But still it takes additionally 4ms (by mistake?) when I repeat condition outside.

(*Here I do not expect extra 4ms of time, because inside CTE condition was unchanged, so there should not be changes in time too, should there?*)

---

try **I3**

Finnaly when I drop `order_id_sys_period_app_period_excl` index, the `BitmapHeapScan` is used again (instead of slower `IndexScan`).
This is most fast query which takes only [3ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Qb6o)

---

Still opened questions:
*Why `IndexScan` was used at **I2** section while `BitmapHeapScan` was used at **I1** section?*
*Why `BitmapIndexScan`s are not applied one after another as it were done at **I3** section? (fastest case)*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RhodiumToad at IRC:

**1. Optimization is not applied because `CTE` contain volatile function.**
(it was acc_ready)

**2. For second query extra time takes JIT generation.**
Compare [9ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/fHjJ) VS [45ms](https://explain.depesz.com/s/hqzZ)